# How to get the text/html value from event.target using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Clipboard.js and am trying to get the text in a `<td>` node using the following:

```
$('.clipboard').click(function(evt) {
    clipboard.copy(evt.target.val()).then(
      function(){console.log("success");},
      function(err){console.log("failure", err);}
    );
});
```

Obviously `.val()` is not a valid method on `evt.target`. What's the correct way of getting the nodes text value using `evt` here?

Comment: Just wrap it up in `$()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be

```
$(evt.target).text()
```

Answer (score 25):

```
evt.target.innerText
```

This will give you text value and innerHtml will give you entire content

Answer (score 0):

Inside `$('.clipboard').click(function(evt) { });` you can use the "this" keyword.

If you run `console.log( $(this) )` you will have the element which was clicked. In this case it would be the .clipboard element.

Then to use the text value: `console.log( $(this).text() );`

```
$('.clipboard').click(function(evt) {

    var clicked_element_text = $(this).text();

    clipboard.copy(clicked_element_text).then(

        // Do something with clicked_element_text 

        function(){console.log("success");},
        function(err){console.log("failure", err);}
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing plain JavaScript and jQuery. In your callback the `evt` is an Event-Object. The `evt.target` is a DOM-Element.

To use a jQuery-Method you need to create a jQuery-Object by wrapping it inside `$()`.

So it should become either: `$(evt.target).text()` or `$(evt.target).html()`, depending on either your need of just the plain text or your need of the inside-html.

```
$('.clipboard').click(function(evt) {
    var $target = $(evt.target);
    clipboard.copy($target.text()).then(
      function(){console.log("success");},
      function(err){console.log("failure", err);}
    );
});
```